# Add forward and back button on a custom toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar, back-button, uitoolbar

I am trying to add forward and back button on custom toolbar in android studio I have tried adding it as a menu as well as separate buttons but every time when I run the app the buttons are not appearing. Code is working fine I am not able to detect what am i missing here. Here is the code :

XML

```
       <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menu_icon"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/menu"
                />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3">


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/back"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_ios_24">

                </Button>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/forward"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_forward_ios_24">

                </Button>

                <Button
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/refresh"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_refresh_24"
                    android:layout_marginStart="40dp" />

            </LinearLayout>




        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pb"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:progress="50"
                android:progressTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:indeterminateDuration="2000"
                android:maxHeight="3dp"
                android:minHeight="3dp"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

        </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="15dp"
            >

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            </WebView>


        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>







    </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
public class Webview extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private WebView webview;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    ImageView menuicon, forward, back, refresh;
    static final float END_SCALE = 0.7f;
    LinearLayout contentView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);


        navigationDrawer();
        Loadweb();

    }

    private void toolbuttons() {


        forward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onForwardPressed();
            }
        });

        refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                webview.reload();
            }
        });


    }


    private void Loadweb() {

        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            }

        });
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

        });
        webview.loadUrl("https://www.nationalsavings.com.pk/index.php");
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {


            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        webview.reload();
                    }
                }, 3000);
            }


        });

        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));


        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }


    private void navigationDrawer() {

        //navigation view

        navigationView.bringToFront();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
        menuicon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (drawer.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START))
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                else drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

            }
        });
        animateNavigationDrawer();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.back:
                onBackPressed();
                break;

            case R.id.forward:
                onForwardPressed();
                break;

            case R.id.refresh:
                webview.reload();
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (drawer.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START) || webview.canGoBack()) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            webview.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }

    public void onForwardPressed() {

        if (webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't go back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


    private void animateNavigationDrawer() {

        drawer.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        //Add any color or remove it to use the default one!
        //To make it transparent use Color.Transparent in side setScrimColor();
        //drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

                // Scale the View based on current slide offset
                final float diffScaledOffset = slideOffset * (1 - END_SCALE);
                final float offsetScale = 1 - diffScaledOffset;
                contentView.setScaleX(offsetScale);
                contentView.setScaleY(offsetScale);

                // Translate the View, accounting for the scaled width
                final float xOffset = drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset;
                final float xOffsetDiff = contentView.getWidth() * diffScaledOffset / 2;
                final float xTranslation = xOffset - xOffsetDiff;
                contentView.setTranslationX(xTranslation);
            }
        });


    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            // Handle the camera action
            webview.loadUrl("https://www.nationalsavings.com.pk/index.php");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_privacy_policy) {
            webview.loadUrl("https://www.nationalsavings.com.pk/privacy-policy.php");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            Intent shareintent = new Intent();
            shareintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://www.nationalsavings.com.pk/index.php");
            shareintent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareintent, "Share via"));
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```